# react-chartjs-2 (Create Custom Labels for Legend)

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I'm trying to update the format of words within a legend in react-chartjs-2.

For example:

1. `{{name}}_365` > `{{name}} (LY)` (e.g., `Clicks_365` > `Clicks (LY)`)
2. `{{name}}_Rel_YoY` > `{{name}} (% Change)` (e.g., `Clicks_Rel_YoY` > `Clicks (% Change)`)

Here's what I've tried, but I haven't been able to get it to work. Any ideas how to fix?

```
const chartJsOptions = (datasetLabels: string[]) => {
    console.log('datasetLabels', datasetLabels)

    const generateLabel = (text: string) => {
        if (text.endsWith('_365')) {
            return text.replace('_365', ' (LY)');
        } else if (text.endsWith('_Rel_YoY')) {
            return text.replace('_Rel_YoY', ' (% Change)');
        } else if (text.endsWith('_Abs_YoY')) {
            return text.replace('_Abs_YoY', ' (Abs Change)');
        }
        return text;
    };

    return {
        plugins: {         
            legend: { 
                position: 'bottom',
                legend: {
                    position: 'bottom',
                    labels: {
                        generateLabels: function(chart: any) {
                            const originalLabelsGenerator = chart.defaults.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels;
                            const labels = originalLabelsGenerator.call(this, chart);
    
                            for (let i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                                labels[i].text = generateLabel(labels[i].text);
                            }

                            return labels;
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a legend inside another legend, I think this is not correct

```
legend: { 
  position: 'bottom',
  legend: {
    position: 'bottom',
```